# android - move panorama with sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, panoramas

I have a big problem.
I have a cubic panorama and I would move that panorama with sensors.

I get the control of accelerometer but I don't know how to move the panorama.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
...
...

PLCubicPanorama cubicPanorama = new PLCubicPanorama();
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cubefront), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationFront);
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cubeback), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationBack);
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cubeleft), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationLeft);
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cuberight), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationRight);
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cubetop), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationUp);
cubicPanorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.apollo01_cubebottom), false), PLCubeFaceOrientation.PLCubeFaceOrientationDown);

this.load(new PLJSONLoader("res://raw/json_cubic"), true, new PLTransitionBlend(2.0f));
this.setPanorama(cubicPanorama);
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      Log.i("SENSORE", "TYPE_ACCELEROMETER");
              //HOW TO MOVE THE PANORAMA??
            }
}
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Accelerometer is just for acceleration. Use the `Gyroscope` for direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response..Can you guide me to do this task?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro

Comment: Yes..I understand how manage but I can't move the panorama..

Comment: did you manage to find how to use sensors in this example? if so, please let me know, im facing the same issue

Comment: I leave that project and I realize the panorama with http://krpano.com/ tool.